# CSS - How to change border height in linear-gradient?

Tags: css

I have the following table:

[image]

and this css for the table border:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #B3B3B3 20%) 0 0 0 1;
```

i want the border ends where the last list item bullet ends. Can i achieve this with the border-image property? Or is this possible at all? By the way the height of the list items may vary, not every item has the exact same height.

So this should be the result:

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to set or know the height of the very last item?

Comment: If you could know the height, I would say yes. If not, you could use JavaScript to set the border-image based on the height of the last item. And add a value like this: `border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,  #b3b3b3 20%, #b3b3b3 calc(100% - 25px), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(100% - 25px)) 0 0 0 1;` Where you change the value of `25px` to be changed to whatever the offest the list-style-item is from the bottom.

Comment: i would accept the answer if you can write it as an answer to question ;)

Comment: by the way, do u know how i can make the length of gradient part constant. Currently the gradient is percentual and if i have 1000 items, the upper part of the border will not be seen.. i would actually like to have a constant height for gradient part, only 20px i.e. actually it does not have to be gradient anymore :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would be able to know the height of the either the `ul` or at least the last `li`, then a css only solution is definitely possible; otherwise, it gets tricky.

The `linear-gradient` function takes four values (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Values), one of which is the `color-stop-list`. If you set one stop to end and another to begin at the same point (either a percentage or a length, such as pixels), then you get a solid line at that stop with the defined or default angle.

So, you can get the gradient to stop at a fixed pixel point as follows:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #b3b3b3 20%, #b3b3b3 calc(100% - 25px), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(100% - 25px))
```

Here, I am changing from the main color to a color with `opacity: 0` at a point `25px` from the full height of the box (since we are using `to bottom`). You can try to eyeball this for you project, or use JavaScript via `Element.getBoundingClientRect().height` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on the last `li` to calculate the position of the `list-item-type` based on how you define that in your css.

To answer the question in your last comment, use the same logic and set a stop point `20px` in:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20px, #b3b3b3 20px, #b3b3b3 calc(100% - 25px), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(100% - 25px))
```

Having said this you may consider handling the border on each individual `li` rather than on the `ul`, which would make it much easier to handle without JavaScript. You would then only need to supply `linear-gradient` values on the `ul>li:first-child` and `ul>li:last-child` using the principles above. Just keep in mind that if you use `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` on any `li` in the list, you will see gaps in your border.